# setresuid operation not permitted when calling via php

Tags: apache2, sudo, php

I've got following Problem:
my Apache and PHP script are running as user www-data.

I want to call a script that can only be executed as root, so I added a new File to
/etc/sudoers.d to allow this command for the www-data user:

```
echo390:/var/www/html# cat /etc/sudoers.d/iptables
www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables
```

my PHP script looks as follows:

```
<?php
$command = '"/usr/bin/sudo" "/sbin/iptables" -L  -v -n | grep "220.177.198.43"';
echo 'Benutzer: '.exec('whoami').'<br/>';
echo 'Command: '.$command.'<br/>';
$result = array();
exec($command,$result);
print_r($result);
?>
```

if I call the script from the command line via: 
sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php test.php
everything runs as expected, but when I call the script via Apache, 
I got the following error in apache2/error.log:

```
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, -1, -1): Operation not permitted
```

I've Upgraded Ubuntu from 12.02 to 14.04 
The Same script had run in Ubuntu 12.02 without any problems. 
Can anybody help me? where is the error here?

groups for www-data:
`echo390:~$ groups www-data`
shows
`www-data : www-data`

As info:
I use the [Apache-mpm-itk module](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net) 
sothat every apache virtual host runs under a separate user id. 
So how do you allow a specific Apache user to execute a specific shell script with 
root privileges (in php etc)?

Thanks in advance and kind regards
Ravermeister

Comment: could you post `groups www-data` output?

Comment: Hi, output is:  `echo390:~$ groups www-data`  shows:  `www-data : www-data`

Comment: Did you add sudoers directive for all user and groups defined in Apache-mpm-itk directive? It seems that sudo doesn't know user uid, are you using AssignUserID or AssignUserIDExpr?

Comment: Hi, I used `AssignUserID www-data www-data`  
for this virtual host, it is the default host anyway.  
and this was the first sudo directive I've added to the /etc/sudoers.d   
(The system users were all added to the group sudo via `adduser mySystemUser sudo`
and there are running apache instances with users who **do not** have sudo rights

Comment: In Apache-mpm-itk documentation I found: Since mpm-itk has to be able to setuid(), it runs as root (although restricted with POSIX capabilities and seccomp v2 where possible) until the request is parsed and the vhost determined. Does apache daemon runs as root or runs as www-data and mpm-itk module grants root privilege?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that, I start my apache instance with `sudo service apache2 start` when I do a `sudo ps -aux | grep apache2` I see an instance running as root, and instances running as the vhost user, so I guess _yes_

Comment: Could you check how `/etc/init.d/apache2` script starts apache2 daemon? I guess something like `su - user -c command`.

Comment: no in the /etc/init.d/apache2 script the /usr/sbin/apache2ctl command is used. inside this script it calls $HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENTS} -k $ARGV $HTTPD is the path to the apache2 executable, and the $APACHE_ARGUMENTS and $ARGV are generated with the config files of the vhosts and from /etc/apache2  **so no** `su - user -c command` **is not used**

Comment: I apologize for my difficulty in understanding, why is `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` used, as far as I know command `service apache2 start` runs `/etc/init.d/apache2` script and this is the script that runs at reboot. I may have misunderstood your reply.

Comment: Inside of the script /etc/init.d/apache 
the command /usr/sbin/apache2ctl is used to start the apache daemon

Comment: Okey, and this is done without any kind of sudo command?

Comment: correct. 
I guess the user switching is done **inside** the apache-mpm-itk instance. that would also explain why I have **one** apache instance running under root

Answer (score 6):

Fix for `apache2.4` and `mpm-itk`
Place this in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf`

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    LimitUIDRange 0 6000
    LimitGIDRange 0 6000
</IfModule>
```

and restart `apache`.

This is not needed on `apache2.2` but once I upgraded to `apache2.4` my PHP scripts that were using `shell_exec` and `sudo` stopped working.

Comment: This is strange but worked for me.

Comment: A PRO tip indeed !

Answer (score 1):

I find it rather weird to suggest to disable the mpm-itk as there might be a reason why it is actually used.

We use mpm-itk (version 2.4.7-02) with apache 2.4 and it works perfectly. The only thing to consider here are the new configuration directives

```
LimitUIDRange
```

and

```
LimitGIDRange
```

These directives define, which UIDs and GIDs mpm-itk can use (via setuid/setguid). As you obviously want it to be able to become root, your lower range must be ID 0. The following configuration will work here:

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    LimitUIDRange 0 6000
    LimitGIDRange 0 6000
</IfModule>
```

Be aware, the the upper border should include all user UID/GID combinations that you want to use within your configuration via AssignUserID.

Note that you can configure this for each virtual host you have. Note too, that you need a Linux kernel 3.5.0 or higher for this.

Comment: Hit this feature, but LimitUIDRange is not helping. If I put it in a virtualhost, it says that it can't be put on a virtualhost, if I put outside I don't get any errors but it doesn't solve anything. Suggestions? (Ubuntu 14.04 with apache 2.4 with mpm-itk)

Answer (score 0):

Your sudoers configuration is right, in fact when you exec:

```
  sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php test.php
```

it work as expected.

In normal operation, your **apache** runs as **root** and use **mpm-itk** module. Here is the problem.

According to [mpm-itk documentation](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/):

> Since mpm-itk has to be able to **setuid()**, it runs as root (although
>   restricted with POSIX capabilities and seccomp v2 where possible)
>   until the request is parsed and the vhost determined.

and:

> mpm-itk is based on the traditional prefork MPM, which means it's
>   non-threaded; .... You will also take
>   an additional performance hit over prefork, since there's an extra
>   fork per request.

This means that **mpm-itk** fork **apache** process and use setuid() in order to assign desired user to each virtual host.

According to [setuid manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man2/setuid.2.html):

> The setuid() function checks the effective user ID of the caller and
>   if it is the superuser, all  process-related  user  ID's are  set  to 
>   uid.   After  this has occurred, it is impossible for the program to
>   regain root privileges.

This could explain already, but not convinced, I downloaded the source of **mpm-itk** and I notice that it change [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) permit and restrict the uid range from 1 to UINT_MAX.

> If  a  thread  drops a capability from its permitted set, it can never
>   reacquire that capability

My conclusion is that by using **mpm-itk** your php scripts can't gain root permission.

If you have the chance, you can check if running **apache** as **www-data** and disabling **mpm-itk** module your **test.php** works.